# How should url be when giving internal link

Tags: seo, internal-links

I saw in an article that when internal linking, it should be given from the home page.

If I give an example...

suggested url:   /category/article

normally existing:  [www.example.com/category/article](http://www.example.com/category/article)

Which one is good for SEO?

Comment: I don't think it matters for SEO. However, the fully qualified URL might help if someone clone's your site or content.  I'm pretty sure that several of us on this forum use the shorter links.

Comment: Don't forget to check for existing questions that already have answers before asking new ones!

Comment: @Trebor "might help if someone clone's your site or content." any good tool should be able to clone and rewrite the links to make them absolute if needed. That shouldn't change the motivation to do one way or another at the site creation side.